# ASP.NET Web API extending DefaultDirectRouteProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to create a `CustomerDefaultDirectRouteProvider` that extends `DefaultDirectRouteProvider` in Web API 2.2, as in [this example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22#ARI). However, when I implement the method `GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)`, I get the error "no suitable method found to override".

I am able to override `GetActionRouteFactories(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)`, but the `ActionDescriptor` class does not have the method `GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>`.

I am importing the following namespaces:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Routing;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
```

Am I missing some, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing MVC and WebAPI. Both have the `DefaultDirectRouteProvider` class. I suggest you remove the `.Mvc`-namespaces and use the one from `System.Web.Http.Routing`.